# How do I stop OS X Lion from sleeping when I close the lid on my new Air?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, sleep, macbook-air

Either `pmset noidle` doesn't work, or "sleep" doesn't mean what I think it means.  If I'm playing Pandora and I shut my lid, I want the music to keep playing.  Apparently there's an app called InsomniaX but I can't find a reputable version that is advertised as working with Lion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that there is a way without any third party applications. [InsomniaX 2.0](http://semaja2.net/archives/206) that will allow you to control the lid behavior.

> InsomniaX disables the sleep mode on a Apple Laptop allowing you to
>   play music through speakers while it's closed. Also adds the option to
>   enable hibernation mode. We are currently looking for a new icon set
>   for InsomniaX, if anyone can produce a new "lickable" set please
>   contact the help desk

Comment: Quote from the question: *> Apparently there's an app called InsomniaX but I can't find a reputable version that is advertised as working with Lion.* – I fixed your link to a 2.0 version that is supposed to work with 10.7